# Angular cannot find controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, path

I am doing a very simple task, just establish a connection between the `container`of the `index.html` and the `controller.js`. Problem is,  when I open the console on the browser does not print anything but throws:

> Error: $controller:ctrlreg
>   A controller with this name is not registered.

[image]

Here is my eventController.js file:

```
function AppCtrl() {
console.log("Event Controller");
}
```

and this is the index:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>trafiyaAPI</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <h1>API</h1>

        <table class="table">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Long</th>
                    <th>Lat</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers/controllerEvent.js"></script>
</body>
```

The structure of the project is:

[image]

I appreciate any help

Comment: Global function controller syntax is deprecated since 1.3. Use `angular.module('appName').controller('controllerName', function` syntax.

Comment: thanks, I just came to notice!